# Decimal not equal as expected

Tags: python

Why `Decimal(0.01)` is equal `Decimal('0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between `Decimal('0.01')` and `Decimal(0.01)`.

First converts str into Decimal (and `Decimal('0.01')` is equal `Decimal('0.01')`,

Second converts float into Decimal (that's why `Decimal(0.01)` is equal `Decimal('0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375')`

Comment: I don't understand the logic of deletion questions and answers which explains exact problem. Nobody would look for FLOATING POINT MATH BROKEN in Decimal(0.01). I solved the problem when I discover that 0.01 is a float. But earlier it was very confusing.

Comment: I'm with you man. Although this information is in the duplicate question, it is buried deep in an answer with few upvotes, so I think it's worth having this specific question and your answer. But not everyone agrees with me on this.

Comment: But there are too many questions are about floating point numbers being "broken" in every language, so I understand the rapid closing of such questions with a pointer to that question with its very detailed answers.